# Which wires do I connect to my new ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling, ceiling-fan, junction-box

I looked all over the internet and my outlet box seems to have unorthodox wiring/ colors.

On the ceiling outlet box I have 3 thick wires,  red, white and green, and a fourth single little wire that is orange.

On the ceiling fan there is motor, light and neutral wire. There is also a little green wire connected to the mount which I think is the ground wire.

What connects to what?

I would like to add that this condo building is about 8 years old. So it's fairly new.

Comment: You have specified that the wire colors are  unorthodox. Can you specify what this is in relation to? Wire color usage does vary from region to region and yet we have no clue as to what region that you hale from.

Comment: What was attached to the wires in the ceiling outlet box before it was opened up to contemplate the connection of your new ceiling fan? Are there one or more switches on the wall nearby that controlled the previous fixture?

Comment: I think a pic of the ceiling box is in order. What you describe having makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

What was there before?  By the colors you describe, I suspect there was a hard wired smoke detector there, the smaller orange wire is daisy chained to all detectors so if one detects smoke/Co/extreme heat, all detectors go into alarm mode.  If you removed a smoke detector, you have violated local codes!